# Cygwin replace all instances of a character in a text file

Tags: string, bash, shell, command-line, cygwin

I have a text file that has numerous instances of the character '^'. I need all those instances replaced with a '['.

I prefer to use cygwin but would use windows command prompt if there is a direct way to do this. My initial instinct was to use Access (no other DB installed) to use the 'replace' function, but as I'm connecting using Jet - apparently this is not possible as per [Exception when trying to execute "REPLACE" against MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834536/exception-when-trying-to-execute-replace-against-ms-access)

What's the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/\^/\[/g' myfile
```

Comment: Perfect! People like you make this site awesome. Instant answer, instant correction by someone and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this:   sed 's/\^/[/g' //by the command line